# I can't figure out how to iterate my list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
var dog = Animal(true, 5)
var cat = Animal(true, 4)
var turtle = Animal(false, 3)
val animalList = listOf<Animal>(dog, cat, turtle)
```

I want to iterate my animalList and see if the animal is a Mammal

Here is my Animal class below

```
class Animal(isMammal: Boolean, numberOfAnimal: Int) {
    private var _isMammal:Boolean = false
    private var _count: Int = 0
    init {
        _isMammal = isMammal
        _count = numberOfAnimal
    }
    fun getType(): String {
        if(_isMammal) {
            return "Mammal"
        }
        else {
            return "Not A Mammal"
        }
    }
    fun updateCount(modifyAnimalCountBy:Int)
    {
        _count = _count + modifyAnimalCountBy
    }
    fun getCount(): Int {
        return _count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can reduce your `Animal` class to this:

```
data class Animal(var isMammal: Boolean, var count: Int)
```

Then, you can iterate over the list with a simple for-loop. The fact that `isMammal` can be accessed as a boolean makes it easier.

```
for (animal in animalList) if (animal.isMammal) println("$animal is a mammal")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the list with [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html):

```
animalList.forEach { println("The Animal #${it.getCount()} is ${it.getType()}") }
```

Results:

```
The Animal #5 is Mammal
The Animal #4 is Mammal
The Animal #3 is Not A Mammal
```

Or you can create a list of mammals by filtering your list:

```
val mammalList = animalList.filter { it.getType() == "Mammal" }
```